# Why is RuboCop replacing the word "should" with the word "does"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code, rubocop

I'm not sure what is causing it, but the word "should" is being replaced in my code with the word "does". I'm writing a spec in ruby on rails, and I'm trying to follow a BDD approach to my unit tests. One of their recommendations is writing each unit test as a whole sentence, starting with the word, "should", so I wrote the following test:

```
it 'should not return if there are no existing activities on the project' do
end
```

The code is being replaced by the following:

```
it 'does not return if there are no existing activities on the project' do
end
```

Notice that the word "should" has been replaced. Is this RuboCop? If so, what is the rule I disable to prevent this from happening?

If it's not RuboCop, what could it be?

Comment: The [`should_clean` gem](https://github.com/siyelo/should_clean) sounds like a reasonable suspect. Although the doc string is pretty bad since everything returns - even if it returns nil.

Answer (score 4):

Well it is actually something Rubocop does for you through [`RSpec/ExampleWording`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop-rspec/1.6.0/RuboCop/Cop/RSpec/ExampleWording). Rubocop has an Rspec Style guide, you can check the part about ["Should" in Example Docstrings](https://github.com/rubocop/rspec-style-guide#should-in-example-docstrings)

From the docs:

> Do not write 'should' or 'should not' in the beginning of your example
> docstrings. The descriptions represent actual functionality, not what
> might be happening. Use the third person in the present tense.

So disabling it is actually a bad practice and you should stick to the docs and write your docstrings accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable [`RSpec/ExampleWording`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop-rspec/1.6.0/RuboCop/Cop/RSpec/ExampleWording)